# can you iterate over formal arguments in python

Tags: python

I have a method that can take in 3 parameters but if they are not passed in it takes them from the instantiated object. Here is how I set this:

```
def getRepo(self, lcid=None, token=None, repoName=None):
    repoName=self.repo if repoName==None else repoName
    lcid=self.lcid if lcid==None else lcid
    token=self.nwbtoken if token==None else token
```

Is there a better way? I seem to have repeating code. If I could iterate over the arguments and check for None I could do it. I dont want the method to have *args or **kwargs. I want to outline what parameters the method requires.

A

Comment: If you don't want to use `**kwargs` then no, you can't iterate.

Comment: Testing for `None` should always use `is`: `repoName = self.repo if repoName is None else repoName`.

Comment: If the argument can't ever be falsey (0, empty string, empty list, etc.) then just use `or`: `repoName = repoName or self.repo`.

Comment: or you could do: `repoName = repoName or self.repo`. (@Martijn beat me to it)

Comment: yea thats cleaner. Never understand why people downvote questions like this. Its a valid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I may get slated for this but here is a solution I came up with:

```
>>> class trythis:
...      def __init__(self):
...         self.firstvar=1
...         self.secondvar=2
...         self.thirdvar=3
...         self.fourthvar=4
...      def method1(self,firstvar=None,secondvar=None,thirdvar=None):
...         kwargs=vars()
...         for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
...            if k != 'self':
...               if v:
...                  setattr(self, k, v)
...         print("firstvar {}".format(self.firstvar))
...         print("secondvar {}".format(self.secondvar))
...         print("thirdvar {}".format(self.thirdvar))
...         print("fourthvar {}".format(self.fourthvar))
... 
>>> a=trythis()
>>> a.method1()
firstvar 1
secondvar 2
thirdvar 3
fourthvar 4
>>> a.method1(firstvar=9)
firstvar 9
secondvar 2
thirdvar 3
fourthvar 4
>>>
```

So when the method is called with no parameters the instance attributes are used but if a parameter is set on the method call the instance variable is overwritten

Expanding on the above here is a metaclass that achieves this:

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> import inspect
>>> 
>>> def setMethodAttrs(func):
...    @wraps(func)
...    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...        formalArgs=inspect.getargspec(func)[0]
...        if len(args)>1:
...           for x in range(1, len(args)):
...              setattr(args[0], formalArgs[x], args[x])
...        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
...           setattr(vars()['args'][0], k, v)
...        return func(*args, **kwargs)
...    return wrapper
... 
>>> def classAttrs(cls):
...     for key, val in vars(cls).items():
...         if callable(val):
...             setattr(cls,key, setMethodAttrs(val))
...     return cls
...  
... 
>>> 
>>> @classAttrs
... class trythis:
...    def __init__(self):
...       self.firstvar=1
...       self.secondvar=2
...       self.thirdvar=3
...       self.fourthvar=4
...    def method1(self,firstvar=None,secondvar=None,thirdvar=None):
...       print("firstvar {}".format(self.firstvar))
...       print("secondvar {}".format(self.secondvar))
...       print("thirdvar {}".format(self.thirdvar))
...       print("fourthvar {}".format(self.fourthvar))
...    def method2(self, secondvar=None, fourthvar=None):
...       print("firstvar {}".format(self.firstvar))
...       print("secondvar {}".format(self.secondvar))
...       print("thirdvar {}".format(self.thirdvar))
...       print("fourthvar {}".format(self.fourthvar))
...   
...  
... 
>>> a=trythis()
>>> a.method1()
firstvar 1
secondvar 2
thirdvar 3
fourthvar 4
>>> a.method1(firstvar=9)
firstvar 9
secondvar 2
thirdvar 3
fourthvar 4
>>> a.method2(11)
firstvar 9
secondvar 11
thirdvar 3
fourthvar 4
>>> a.method1(19, thirdvar=21)
firstvar 19
secondvar 11
thirdvar 21
fourthvar 4
>>> a.method2(fourthvar=40)
firstvar 19
secondvar 11
thirdvar 21
fourthvar 40
>>>
```

So whatever methods are defined on the trythis class their arguments are set on the trythis object automatically when the methos are called and the code to do this is extracted out into a metaclass

Answer (score 0):

Use **locals()** .  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals

Example based on your function:

```
def getRepo(self, lcid=None, token=None, repoName=None):
    kwargs = locals()
    repoName = kwargs.get('repoName', self.repo)
    lcid = kwargs.get('lcid', self.lcid)
    token = kwargs.get('token', self.nbwtoken)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use kwargs args:

```
def getRepo(self, **kwargs):
    repoName = kwargs.get('repoName', self.repo)
    lcid     = kwargs.get('lcid', self.lcid)
    token    = kwargs.get('token', self.nbwtoken)
```

Using kwargs will allow you to set your local variable to a value that has come through the function call or will set it a default value if no parameter is passed.

When the function is called, you will call it like this :

```
getRepo(repoName='SomeName', lcid='SomeID', token='SomeToken')
```

You can also leave out any of these `named parameters` and your function will use the default value specified by you.

Comment: I stated that I didnt want to use kwargs. The idea was that I would extract the code out into a metaclass when I figured it out (as I did in my eventual answer)